# socket UDP python and RFID antenna

Tags: python, socket

Estoy trabajando con una antena RFID y Raspberry pi (raspbian). La conexión es a través del socket UDP sobre Python 2.7.x.

```
import socket
import sys
import time
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ('192.168.2.16', 49152)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)
while True:
print >>sys.stderr, '\nwaiting to receive message'
data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)
print >>sys.stderr, 'received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address)
print >>sys.stderr, data
if data:
   thetime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()) 
    if len(data) > 0:
        data = data[1:40]
        print "Card Scanned. Tag ID:", data    # print the tag number
        print "card = ", [data], " a las: ", thetime
```

en la actualidad, la aplicación está leyendo esto (haciendo un print): `\ xff \ xff \ x102 \ r \ x01 \ xe2 \ x00 \ x00 \ x165 \ x16 \ x02g \ x140 \ x8f \ x91 \ xd6` ¿Cómo puedo traducir esto a el número de serie de TAG? Debería ser así: `E20000163516026714308F91` y debería guardarse en un archivo .txt

¡Saludos!

Comment: Habitualmente lo que recibirías (cuando la lees de un puerto serie y no por UDP) sería la secuencia de bytes con la codificación ascii del número de serie. Pero no es el caso. La secuencia que tú recibes tiene muchos bytes no-ascii. Falta contexto entonces para resolver el enigma. ¿Quién envía el datagrama UDP? ¿Lo procesa de alguna forma? Por otro lado te quedas con los caracteres [1:40] ¿por qué?

Comment: Además, en tu secuencia aparecen cosas como `\x102` que no es un valor hexadecimal válido (pues es mayor de `ff`) quizás podría ser un `\x10` seguido del ascii `2`. No está claro. Lo mismo pasa luego con `\x165`. ¿Por qué no muestras exactamente lo que aparece en pantalla al ejecutar el programa, en lugar de copiarlo a mano?